# Replication instantly fails with 1032 error; Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s)

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-8.0, docker, debian

I have two databases, which I'm attempting to configure in a master-slave relationship (the eventual goal is to set them as master-master, but I'll settle for getting master-slave working at this point).

We're running the latest version of the official mysql docker container.  The containers are running on separate machines, on the same LAN, sharing the same subnet.  Host servers are Debian 11.

Every time I start the slave process it instantly fails with this error:

```
Last_SQL_Errno: 1032
Last_SQL_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 750. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
```

Slave IO Running shows as Yes, Slave SQL Running shows as No.

In my error log file I get this;

```
2022-07-05T19:55:15.708311Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-07-05T19:55:15.708332Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) starting as process 7
2022-07-05T19:55:15.715516Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.098325Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.254005Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2022-07-05T19:55:16.258426Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.297469Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.297516Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.300092Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.320324Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010604] [Repl] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=93517c58f3d9-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.328571Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010544] [Repl] Failed to open the relay log './acc9194e1549-relay-bin.000003' (relay_log_pos 373).
2022-07-05T19:55:16.328605Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011059] [Repl] Could not find target log file mentioned in relay log info in the index file './93517c58f3d9-relay-bin.index' during relay log initialization.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.330427Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010426] [Repl] Slave: Failed to initialize the master info structure for channel ''; its record may still be present in 'mysql.slave_master_info' table, consider deleting it.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.330453Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010529] [Repl] Failed to create or recover replication info repositories.
2022-07-05T19:55:16.333456Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-07-05T19:55:16.333571Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-07-05T19:55:30.674534Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-07-05T19:55:30.674555Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) starting as process 7
2022-07-05T19:55:30.681786Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.060706Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.214426Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2022-07-05T19:55:31.218776Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.270471Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.270510Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.272531Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.292759Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010604] [Repl] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=8a70b08ea480-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.300239Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010544] [Repl] Failed to open the relay log './acc9194e1549-relay-bin.000003' (relay_log_pos 373).
2022-07-05T19:55:31.300265Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011059] [Repl] Could not find target log file mentioned in relay log info in the index file './8a70b08ea480-relay-bin.index' during relay log initialization.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.305461Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010426] [Repl] Slave: Failed to initialize the master info structure for channel ''; its record may still be present in 'mysql.slave_master_info' table, consider deleting it.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.305489Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010529] [Repl] Failed to create or recover replication info repositories.
2022-07-05T19:55:31.308509Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-07-05T19:55:31.308813Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
2022-07-05T20:03:51.669568Z 12 [ERROR] [MY-013124] [Repl] Slave SQL for channel '': Slave failed to initialize relay log info structure from the repository, Error_code: MY-013124
2022-07-05T20:04:53.417771Z 13 [Warning] [MY-010897] [Repl] Storing MySQL user name or password information in the master info repository is not secure and is therefore not recommended. Please consider using the USER and PASSWORD connection options for START SLAVE; see the 'START SLAVE Syntax' in the MySQL Manual for more information.
2022-07-05T20:04:53.422267Z 13 [System] [MY-010562] [Repl] Slave I/O thread for channel '': connected to master 'repl@192.168.1.34:3306',replication started in log 'FIRST' at position 4
2022-07-05T20:05:08.845383Z 14 [Warning] [MY-010897] [Repl] Storing MySQL user name or password information in the master info repository is not secure and is therefore not recommended. Please consider using the USER and PASSWORD connection options for START SLAVE; see the 'START SLAVE Syntax' in the MySQL Manual for more information.
2022-07-05T20:05:08.847155Z 14 [System] [MY-010562] [Repl] Slave I/O thread for channel '': connected to master 'repl@192.168.1.34:3306',replication started in log 'FIRST' at position 4
2022-07-05T20:05:08.886586Z 16 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave SQL for channel '': Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 750; Could not execute Update_rows event on table Background.CustomServer; Can't find record in 'CustomServer', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log FIRST, end_log_pos 750, Error_code: MY-001032
2022-07-05T20:05:08.887094Z 15 [ERROR] [MY-010586] [Repl] Error running query, slave SQL thread aborted. Fix the problem, and restart the slave SQL thread with "SLAVE START". We stopped at log 'mysql-bin.000001' position 157
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.